# How to access products in custom module

Tags: magento2, module, controllers

```
    <?php
namespace Queueapp\Queueapp\Controller\Query;
// Mage::app();

class Products extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
    /** @var  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    /**      * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context      */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)     {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Blog Index, shows a list of recent blog posts.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {
      //How do I access the products/categories information here and send it to my frontend as json
      $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
      $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Products'));
      echo json_encode("me");
      return $resultPage;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try it like this:

```
<?php
namespace Queueapp\Queueapp\Controller\Query;


class Products extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action 
{
    /** @var  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $productCollectionFactory;
    protected $categoryCollectionFactory;
    /**      * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context      */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,

    ) {

        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Blog Index, shows a list of recent blog posts.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {
      //How do I access the products/categories information here and send it to my frontend as json
      $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
      $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Products'));
      $categories = $this->getCategories();
      $products = $this->getProducts();
      //do what you need with $products and $categories.
      return $resultPage;

    }
    public function getProducts()
    {
         $products = $productCollectionFactory->create();
         //now add filters as you need similar to Magento 1
         $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
         $products->addAttributeToFilter(....);
         //loop through the products and build your array
         $values = [];
         foreach ($products as $product) {
             $values[] = ['name' => $product->getName(), ...];
         }
         return json_encode($values);
    }
    public function getCategories()
    {
         $categories = $categoryCollectionFactory->create();
         //now add filters as you need similar to Magento 1
         $categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');
         $categories->addAttributeToFilter(....);
         //loop through the categories and build your array
         $values = [];
         foreach ($categories as $category) {
             $values[] = ['name' => $category->getName(), ...];
         }
         return json_encode($values);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @marius I'm quite new to magento. kindly help me complete the code above. I want  all products and all information about products. Also I'm guessing instead of return $resultPage;  I should do return $products instead. In order to return json to my frontend

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
namespace Queueapp\Queueapp\Controller\Query;

use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\ConfigLoader;

class Products extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
    /** @var  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page */
    /**
     * Queue collection factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Queue\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    protected $_productRepository;
    protected $product;
    protected $state;
    protected $configLoader;
    protected $objectManager;


    /**
     * Construct
     *
     */
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $_productRepository,
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product,

            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,                 
            State $state,
            \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    ) {
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_productRepository =$_productRepository;
        $this->product  =   $product;
        $this->registry = $registry;       
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;      
    }

    /**
     * Blog Index, shows a list of recent blog posts.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {
      $products = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection()

      $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Products'));
      echo json_encode("me");
      return $resultPage;

    }
}
```

Comment: don't use object manager in classes that are not factories.